# Qt suppress Database errors

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to suppress the error text in a console application. The errors are automatically printed when the Qt database driver encounters any SQL error. What I want to do is, display an user friendly message without the technical error shown. I've not found anything searching that comes close to addressing this.

Comment: For that you'll have to file a bug report on qt's site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a custom message handler with `qInstallMsgHandler()`, but this is **application wide**. I'm not sure if that would give you enough control or not.

- https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler

Example:

```
#include <QtCore>

void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const char *msg) {
  switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg:
    case QtCriticalMsg:
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
      break;
    case QtWarningMsg:
      fprintf(stderr, "A kinder, gentler, warning message.\n", msg);
      break;
    case QtFatalMsg:
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
      abort();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  qInstallMsgHandler(myMessageOutput);
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  qDebug("A debug message");
  qCritical("A critical message");
  qWarning("REALLY TECHNICAL WARNING THAT SCARES SMALL CHILDREN");
  qFatal("A fatal message");
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Accepted as it really is the closest thing until it's addressed by Qt directly.